# There is a way to get current map coordinates?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I'm using the grid-mapcontrol (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?15309,Maps+Control+Type) to display some pins on the map.

I'd like to get new coordinates when the user moves across the map and show new pins for the new region. Is this possible?

I try the method GridMap.GetVisibleRegion but it returns an empty object.

GeneXus 18 Version: 18.0.169539 U2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I test GetVisibleRegion in Android with google maps and works fine. The problem persist in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selection Layer property allows you to obtain the coordinates where the user navigates, it seems to be what you are looking for: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?42223,Selection%20Layer%20property

Note: About GetVisibleRegion method is part of MapsOffline and is not available with google provider: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48363,MapsOffline%20External%20Object

Comment: The only thing to take in care is that SelectionLayer works with a center point and you need to work with a radius. The box coords seems to be more efficient to draw points on the user visible area.